# Nhibernate threading with WPF databinding

Tags: wpf, multithreading, nhibernate, data-binding

How should I do nhibernate threading given the following facts:

1. nhiberante is not thread safe
2. nhibernate entities are databound to a WPF UI, so we must use the UI thread.
3. Some nhibernate queries are slow so we should do the queries on a background thread.

Is it the case that if you want to use nhibernate and WPF data binding you must sacrifice a responsive UI?

Comment: I think that only your third statement is correct. First what do you mean by NHibernate is not thread safe? Second, in a properly written application you are binding view models to your UI, and not your NHibernate domain models.

Comment: We use to wrap nhibernate entity objects to isolate them from view... So, you do your binding with these wrapped objects and when you want persist them, you submit them to nhibernate domain objects and send them to a thread to be saved...

Comment: It is well documented that nhibernate is not thread safe within a session.